# What's the correct way to convert an argument passed to a program to a long double variable?

Tags: c, linux, arguments, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I'm having trouble with this...It compiles, but segfaults immediately when run...Using GDB, I determined that it segfaults while trying to initiate the long doubles.  I feel like atoi might be the wrong function to use, but I tried other similar functions and still got a segfault.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  long double x = atoi(argv[1]);
  char oper = argv[2][0];
  long double y = atoi(argv[3]);
```

Comment: You should check that you have `argc >= 4` before using the argument strings.  Your segmentation fault is most likely because your argument list isn't as long as you thought it was.  As the answers note, `atoi()` is for converting strings into integers; `strtold()` would work for `long double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtold`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

char * e;
errno = 0;
long double d = strtold(argv[1], &e);

if (*e != 0 || errno != 0) { /* Error! Do not consume the result. */ }

// result now in "d"
```

You can use the value of `*e` to figure out whether any part of the string was consumed; see the manual for details. My example just checks whether the *entire* string could be parsed.

<s>I'm actually not sure if there's a thread-safe solution...</s> (Oh, I think it is, because `errno` is thread-local.)

Comment: Okay...I'm having trouble with the second parameter.  How is the end of an argument determined?  The arguments that are being passed are simple equations, such as 1+1, but the character length of each number can be any amount of digits within reason.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `errno` check (including the fact that you have to set `errno` to 0 before you invoke the function if you want the check to be meaningful). I didn't know that `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtod`, and `strtold` could return errors and yet still return a result. Code I have written only checks `if (*e != 0)`.

Comment: In that case, you wil need to write a (reasonable) parser, since `1.01212131+31.1212121*9.12/11.991` would be seen as one argument. On the other hand, if you separare things with spaces, you could just use `argv[]`, so `1.01212131 + 31.1212121 * 9.12 / 11.99` would be 7 different arguments.

Comment: The `errno` check is rather useless, since the only "errors" `strtold` can encounter are overflow/underflow, which for floating point are just 'severe rounding', and probably not something you want to treat as an error. Checking `endptr` covers all the real error conditions (malformed input).

Comment: @R..: Overflow and underflow *are* useful errors, though. And they're even more useful when you're parsing integers (in which case you really mustn't consume the result of the parse), and I want to encourage a pattern here.

Comment: @KerrekSB: They're useful with integers, not so useful with floating point. Do you really want to treat the fact that that `1e-4932L` has slightly less precision than `1e-4931L` as an error?

Comment: @R..: I'd treat is as something that the user should be aware of. I can imagine UI's like "Enter 0 to quit", where you don't just want to quit unexpectedly without any meaningful diagnostics...

Comment: @KerrekSB: In that case, I would only check `errno` in the case where the return value was 0 or infinite. Treating inexact denormals as an error seems very undesirable.

Answer (score 4):

`atoi()` stands for "ascii to integer", which isn't what you want.  You should use an appropriate function — [`strtold(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtold/) is most appropriate, but you can probably use [`sscanf(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sscanf/), too.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to convert a string to a `long double` is

```
long double strtold(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```